# List<T>.Add() objects which also include a List<T>

Tags: c#, list, collections

As I added some objects of class A to my List, I realized that whenever that object changes although it is new’ed again and again, the contents of list change, probably because there is pass by reference, I know that. How can I avoid the change in the case below:

```
List<A> listA;

List<B> listB = SomeFuncReturnsListB();

A a = new A();

a.Attribute1 = listB;

listA.Add(new A(){Attribute1=a.Attribute1});
```

Comment: Maybe this is what you need:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects

Comment: What are you asking for? I'm struggling to understand. Are you asking how to copy a list so that you can add an item to `listA` without it affecting the contents of `listB`, or are you asking about deep cloning objects?

Comment: @Llama The question is about how to add objects to `listA`  without changing its contents. The contents of `listA` keeps changing in the example code given. I mean that all the elements of list turns to the last added element by saying “keeps changing”. My intention was that the reason may be the `listB` in the object `a`.

Comment: Do you mean that listA and listB both contain the same items, even if you add new items to listA? I don't see how listB is "in" object A.

Comment: List of Reference Type does not store actual objects its stores the reference to that object. So if original object changes, same changes reflected in the list.

Comment: @Llama There is a line `a.Attribute1=listB;` which indicates there is a `listB` in `a`. No, listA and listB do not contain the same items. In the question, I wrote all the code how I added objects to listA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use .ToList() to clone without the need of implement a clonage function.

Example:

```
a.Attribute1 = listB.ToList();

listA.Add(a);
```

Note: you need to `using System.Linq;` thank to @Matthew Watson

Comment: How can you call ToList on a List?

Comment: @elizzybeth13 It's using Linq; you need to put `using System.Linq;` at the top of the code file to use it.

Comment: ^ I took for granted that I always have Linq imported. I will edit my response

Comment: Thank you @Matthew Watson. Yes, this worked! Thank you, too Hachiko001

Comment: You can also use `a.Attribute1 = new List<B>(listB);` which I think is slightly more optimized